# Same word files in multiple directories without admin right for multiple users

Tags: git, ms-word, symlink, directory-structure, hardlink

I'm facing a problem at my current project where multiple users need to access hundreds of Word .docx files in multiple directories. They don't have any admin rights to their Windows 10 computers and they wish to have version control connected to it for extra safety.

So I tried to tackle this problem by first creating a Git repo where I stored the documents in a folder. I created a bat file separately with code that downloaded and unziped PortableGit, cloned and downloaded all the docs to their computers. But the problem here where that I tried to create symbolic link with the Git clone, which needs you to execute the bat as a administrator (which is not possible for the end users in this case).
I then tried to create a C# .net Core 3 Windows application with LibGit2Sharp so I could execute the program (so I thought) but I still ended up with complains about admin rights for symbolic links. 
Then I tried to use hard link, but I founded out that Word replace the file after it saves the latest changes and therefore breaks the link.

It feels like I'm just spinning in a circle in a problem that should not be too hard to solve?
The reason that they need to work on the same document in different folders is because there managing templates for legal purposes in different context where they need to be exactly the same. Plus that there's different people in different context/directories.

tldr;
I need to manage a solution where .docx files (could be other types of files in the future) could be edited in multiple different directory without admin right on Windows 10 environment. Version control is also desired.

Comment: FYI doc, docx, xls, xlsx are all binary files in from a SCM perspective so diffing is not possible. Why not put the files on a network share with group edit privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a repository, if symlinks are enabled, Git will attempt to create a symlink that points to a nonexistent file to see if the system and file system support symbolic links.  It's fine if this operation fails, since it just means that the system is not capable of that operation, which is expected on Windows.  However, if it does fail, then Git will check out the symbolic links as files, since there's no other way to represent them.

libgit2 does the same thing since it has to be compatible with Git.

The only reason that you would need to be concerned about this operation failing is if you need symbolic links, which it sounds like you do.  This problem isn't limited to Git; it's a problem with your script and permissions model and symbolic links on Windows.

Git will clone into an existing empty directory, so you can have your script run as administrator and create the directory with symbolic link privileges for the user, then clone as the user.  If you're using Windows 10, you could enable developer mode on the systems; after all, Unix systems have worked fine for several decades with symbolic links.

There are, of course, other solutions, including not using symbolic links and just telling people to look in the proper directory for files.  You could also store these files on a remote system where you've created the symlinks as the administrator and grant everyone remote access to the files, either as one shared repository or as one per user (although sharing a repository is usually a bad idea).  Using hard links isn't a solution, because Git doesn't preserve or honor hard links, so you can't effectively use them together.

Finally, you could use Windows Subsystem for Linux and store the data on a DrvFS (emulated Linux) file system, since it allows symbolic links for all users.

Comment: Remote network system with an admin creating the symlinks is they way we're heading now after this excellent answer. Thank you!